# Find in list of object all items with property exists in other list

Tags: c#, list, iqueryable

i'm new here. My problem is this:

```
List<string> positions = new List<string> { "x1", "x2", "x3 };
var results = _context_WObjects.AsQueryAble();
```

Result returns list of IQueryAble list that have above class:

```
class objectclass {

public string position {get; set; }

public string test {get; set; }

/*... other properties....*/

}
```

How can i find all items with position that has (not contains) one of positions's list?

I've tried:

```
results = results.Where(n1 => positions.Any(n2 => n2 == n1.position));
```

But it wouldn't working!!

The exception error is:

***"Local sequence can not be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except for the Contains operator."***

I've translated from italian.

Thanks
Very much
Cris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. You cannot use `Any` with a local collection like this `List<string>` but you can use `Contains`. You also want `!Contains`:

```
results = results.Where(n1 => !positions.Contains(n1.position));
```

Comment: Ehm not contains but if equal one of position list i will correct the answer... sorry

Comment: Ah ok!  Thanks very much!